# how to handle response code of mutiple network call in a single line in android

Tags: android, http-response-codes

it is my interview questions.Im searching in various sites & tried lot but im unable to find solution.
scenario :
first in android app network call for authorization called if its success  then other network calls going in timer it takes around 10 to 20 calls.in that if any one call response code is other than 200 then again need to call authorization call .
here condition : we cannot put our response code handling logic in each network call logic.We need to put in a single line so that it will applicable for all calls

how to do in android?

Answer (score 1):

This case can be handled with callbacks we get from network libraries we use.

personally I use Volley for network calls, Since it's from google, My clients wanted to stick with it. No hate to Retrofit and OkHttp here.

Basically you can create a common adapter by extending Request class of Volley,
The constructor of your adapter would expect you to pass error listener to the supper method.

```
public class MyVolleyRequest<T> extends Request<T>
{
public MyVolleyRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> myClass, String requestBody,
                   Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url , errorListener);
   // Other initialization.
      }
 // Rest of the code
}
```

Since your constructor of the adapter demands an instance of ErrorListner with every network call, You can pass `postLoginErrorResponse`  for all the subsequent network call of post login.

```
  ErrorListener postLoginErrorResponse = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       // Call the authentication flow.
                }
            });
```

Comment: here i dont need error listener.assuming if status code 200 means ok othwise it call for token.how we can achieve this by ur code

Comment: Every Non 200 HTTP codes will land at error listener. So if you want to perform some recurring call. You can use this block of call back.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `OkHttp` or `Retrofit`, you can take benefit of `Call Adapters`.
Call Adapters are simply a network response handler, where you'll be convert incoming response from one form to another.

First you'll have to create a `CallAdapter`, then a `CallAdapterFactory`. And finally, you'll be passing the `factory` to `Retrofit` or `OkHttpClient`. That's it.

You can learn creating your own call adapters from [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/building-your-own-retrofit-call-adapter-b198169bab69)